# supportsWeakPointers vs objc_arc_weak_unavailable

Tags: objective-c

I think that both methods are equivalent.

Do you know the difference?

> [objc_arc_weak_unavailable](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) objc_arc_weak_unavailable attribute on
>   the class's interface declaration. A retainable object pointer type is
>   weak-unavailable if is a pointer to an (optionally protocol-qualified)
>   Objective-C class T where T or one of its superclasses has the
>   objc_arc_weak_unavailable attribute. A program is ill-formed if it
>   applies the __weak ownership qualifier to a weak-unavailable type or
>   if the value operand of a weak assignment operation has a
>   weak-unavailable type.
>
> [supportsWeakPointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788108/the-role-of-supportsweakpointers)    If you you [sic] find that you must
>   implement custom retain or release methods, then you must also
>   implement the following method in your class:
>
> ```
> -(BOOL)supportsWeakPointers { return NO; }
> ```
>
> This method will prevent weak pointers from being formed to your objects. You are strongly encouraged to find a solution that doesn’t
>   require implementing your own retain and release methods instead of
>   doing this.

**Note:** By checking [the LLVM parser](https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/include/clang/Basic/Attr.td?diff_format=h&view=markup&sortby=date) I found that the right symbol is `objc_arc_weak_reference_unavailable`, that is:

```
__attribute__((objc_arc_weak_reference_unavailable))
@interface Point : NSObject 

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Significantly, `objc_arc_weak_unavailable` is a compile time option (you can also declare it using `NS_AUTOMATED_REFCOUNT_WEAK_UNAVAILABLE`) whereas supportWeakPointers is a runtime call. [This question addresses why you might use this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7788108/449161)